# Resizing Image Nginx on the Fly with Backend S3

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I've already installed nginx with module http image filter module and all dependencies. my nginx version 1.8.0.

here's my script :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.domain.com;

        location ~* / {
                proxy_pass http://mydomain.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com;
        }

        location ~* ^/resize/([\d\-]+)x([\d\-]+)/(.+)$ {
            alias http://mydomain.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/$3;
            image_filter resize $1 $2;
            image_filter_buffer 2M;
            error_page 415 = /empty;
        }

        location ~* ^/crop/([\d\-]+)x([\d\-]+)/(.+)$ {
            alias http://mydomain.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/$3;
            image_filter crop $1 $2;
            image_filter_buffer 2M;
            error_page 415 = /empty;
        }

        location = /empty {
            empty_gif;
        }
    }
```

when i request http://my.domain.com/some_image.jpg, it's return no error

but when i try with http://my.domain.com/resize/300x300/some_image.jpg, it return 404 or not found

**Update#1**

I've change :

```
location ~* / {
```

to :

```
location / {
```

it's fix the error on my config.

Comment: Try proxy_pass, not an alias

Comment: it's still same ... i don't know why